# asp.net webapi jsonserializer straemreader gets 1 minute blocked_time

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a web app service hosted on Azure, every few minutes a Put operation is waiting for a minute to get a response. Using application insights Profiler, I can see that `JsonTextReader.Read` operation while trying to `StreamReader.Read` from request body, is getting BLOCKED_TIME for a complete 1 minute. The request size is approximately 700 bytes, and though the object may be a little complex, it does getting deserialized just fine most of the time.

[image: profiler screen shot]

I've manage to drill down a bit more inside the thread , the blocked operation is SwapContext_PatchLdMxCsr - not sure what it means:

[profiler screen shot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7Rhc.jpg)

Comment: It looks like that Read operation waits for a stream to provide data. Can it be the case that whoever makes this call doesn't send a request in full?

Comment: after the block the flow continues as expected, so I assume the request is full

Comment: this might mean that this code waits till the full request is received...

Comment: Thank you, how can I check this approach ? I see that the request arrived to the server - how can I tell that it's complete ?

Comment: direct way :tcp dump to see if packets are fragmented. indirect: send bigger requests to see if that increases chances of blocks.